# What is the BeaconLayout for URIBeacon?

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I'm trying to detect (pre Eddystone) [uri-beacon](https://github.com/google/uribeacon) using the [android-beacon-library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html), but it's not clear to me how the transform the [uri-beacon spec](https://github.com/google/uribeacon/blob/uribeacon-final/specification/AdvertisingMode.md#uribeacon-advertising-data) into a [BeaconLayout](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html#setBeaconLayout(java.lang.String)) string.

Comparing [example EddyStone strings](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html) to the [EddyStone spec](https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md) is also confusing. The byte offsets don't seem to match. I must be missing something critical here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the latest specification [here](https://github.com/google/uribeacon/blob/09a633ec2a3975377c282954fd2c6f2421b2644a/specification/README.md), you may be able to decode a pre-Eddystone URI beacon with the following:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=fed8,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v"));
```

**Important:**  I have not tested this myself, and since I don't have access to an original URI beacon, I can't guarantee that it will work.  If you do detect a beacon with this layout, you'll need to decode the identifier into a URL like this:

```
String url = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.uncompress(beacon.getId1().toByteArray());
```

The above uncompress method won't work with the urn:uuid: scheme of the original URI Beacon format, but it will uncompress regular URLs.

You can read more about working with URL Beacons with the Android Beacon Library here:  https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html

If you do get this working, please confirm the layout by accepting this answer or commenting below.  I can then add the layout to the build-in constants and documentation for the library.

Full Disclosure:  I am lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something wrong because the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion()` callback is returning `0` beacons.

03-22 14:35:14.552 25628-25628/com.example.wilsonpage.myapplication D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
03-22 14:35:14.554 25628-25628/com.example.wilsonpage.myapplication D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
03-22 14:35:14.557 25628-25791/com.example.wilsonpage.myapplication D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand how the spec maps to the layout string. For example in the uribeacon spec it say the txpower value is at offset 9, but the layout sting you've given appears to state it to be at offset `3-3`?

Comment: BTW I'm working with the 'Working With Eddystone URL' (https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html) example as a base, and simply altering the `.setBeaconLayout` string.

Comment: The uri-beacon advertisement looks like: [2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 216, 254, 19, 22, 216, 254, 0, 242, 3, 103, 111, 111, 46, 103, 108, 47, 104, 113, 66, 88, 69, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @wilsonpage, I was able to parse the byte sequence you showed above successfully using the beacon layout expression I showed you.  I actually put those exact bytes into a unit test in the Android Beacon Library and was able to parse the URL.  Perhaps something else is preventing detection in your code?  You can see the unit test here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/358/files

Comment: that's good news! Can you explain how the beacon layout expression maps to the spec/byte-sequence?

Comment: BLE adverts are subdivided into PDUs.  Beacon layout expression are relative to the first byte after the PDU type byte.  In the bytes you show, it is the second PDU that is important:  19, 22, 216, 254, 0, 242, 3, 103...  The first two bytes are the length and the PDU type.  The beacon layout offsets are after this.  A Service UUID of fed8 is expected at offset 0-1, which it is there (216 and 254 correspond to d8 fe in little endian order).  It matches 0 at offset 2 and then pulls the power byte out of offset 3 and the identifier out of the remaining bytes starting with offset 4.